# How do intelligent agents accept an organizational structure and shape their whole paradigm?

Tags: agents-jade, agents

I want to change the whole structure of a multi agent system [an introduction to multi agent organizational paradigms- by `Mr. Horling`](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/745f/ba94b0f323cda26f05a0f0c22dba534411bd.pdf), I mean I want to measure a multi agent system's performance and under some circumstances I need to ask the multi agent system to change it's structure. for example from a hierarchical model to a society model.

MY exact problem is that how can I tell agents hey you, change your structure? How can I write this in java using JADE framework?

Can any body help me with this? Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be hard to find a mature JADE extension framework to deal with organizations where it would be easier to change the organization as you intent. The book [Developing Multi-Agent System with JADE](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Developing+Multi+Agent+Systems+with+JADE-p-9780470057476) shows some techniques what for me looks like ad hoc solutions like the use of Contract Net Protocol to organize and later to coordinate agents.

The way it seems to be better to design and make adjustements on the organizational structure is using a mature framework that has organization as a first-class programming dimension, as in [JaCaMo](http://jacamo.sourceforge.net/). With this framework the organization scheme is define in a XML file (using a structure defined by the framework Moise). It uses CArtAgO artifacts to coordinate the agents according to the defined relations, norms, agent's roles and commitements.